# C# error: delegate is local function and must therefore always have a body

Tags: c#, vsto

Trying to mimic a code from a [Winform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/) app to a [VSTO Add-In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-word?view=vs-2017). It works in Winform but  gives the following error in [ThisAddIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2017) class of the VSTO app. *Question*: How can I make it work in the VSTO Addin as well?

Error:

> > delegate is local function and must therefore always have a body

**Relevant code in Winform's Form class** [it works]:

```
/// <summary>This event handler is called when myApp.exe closes.</summary>
void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // remove the event
  ((Process) sender).Exited -= p_Exited;

  // the UI thread is running asynchronous to myApp.exe closing
  // that's why we can't call CheckIfPassed(); directly
  Invoke(new IsPassedDelegate(CheckIfPassed));
}

delegate void IsPassedDelegate();
```

**Relevant code in VSTO App's ThisAddIn class** [gives error at the last line: 'delegate void IsPassedDelegate();']:

```
/// <summary>This event handler is called when myApp.exe closes.</summary>
void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // remove the event
  ((Process) sender).Exited -= p_Exited;

  // the UI thread is running asynchronous to myApp.exe closing
  // that's why we can't call CheckIfPassed(); directly
  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new IsPassedDelegate(CheckIfPassed));
}

delegate void IsPassedDelegate();
```

Comment: A [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) is a function declared within another. Are you sure the `delegate` line is not inside another method?

Comment: @RufusL It was inside another method. After moving it outside, the issue was resolved. Thank you very much for pointing out a possible cause of the issue. I should start reading new features in `C# 7.0`. You may want to change your comment to a Response briefly describing the possible causes of the issue . I will mark your response as an answer so others can benefit.